# Relativistic electrodynamics between two point charges moving in perpendicular directions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames

Let there be two point charges, positive or negative, having velocities in directions perpendicular to each other. I need to evaluate the total interactive force on those (Lorentz force).

I do it by assuming magnetic force is an effect of special relativity on the electrostatic force. In doing so I am finding a value half of the Lorentz force predicted in classical electrodynamics. I have proceeded with many different possible approaches, but the result is always the same. Why is it so?

Here is my reasoning:
$$v_\text{rel}= \frac{\vec{V}-\vec{U}}{1-\vec{V}\cdot\vec{U}/c^2}$$
Since the charges are moving perpendicular to each other in the static (lab) frame, $V\cdot U=0$.
The Lorentz factor between two frames, (1) the rest frame of the "field charge" $Q$ and (2) the rest frame of the "test charge" $q$ is given by
$$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(u^2+v^2)/c^2}}$$
Now I evaluate the proper force (considering purely electrostatic force) exerted by $Q$ on $q$, in the rest frame of $q$.
$$\begin{align}
E_\perp q &= \gamma E_{0\perp} q &
E_\parallel q &= E_{0\parallel} q
\end{align}$$
where $E_0$ is the field at $q$ in the rest frame of $Q$.

After finding these two forces, I resolved them in the X and Y directions, where X is the direction in which $Q$ moves and Y is the direction in which $q$ moves, both in the lab frame.
$$\begin{align}
\sin\theta &= \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}} &
\cos\theta &= \frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}
\end{align}$$
Then I get
$$\begin{align}
F_x &= \frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2} E_0 q &
F_y &= \biggl(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}\biggr)E_0
\end{align}$$
Now these forces will produce proper acceleration in their respective directions in the rest frame of $q$.
$$\begin{align}
\alpha_x &= \frac{F_x}{m_0} &
\alpha_y &= \frac{F_y}{m_0}
\end{align}$$
where $m_0$ is the rest mass of the particle with charge $q$.
After that I proceed to transfer these forces to the lab frame.
Acceleration of $q$ with respect to the lab is given by
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} &= \frac{1}{\gamma^2}\alpha_x & \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} &= \frac{1}{\gamma^3}\alpha_y
\end{align}$$
Obviously here $\gamma$ is given by
$$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}$$
so
$$\begin{align}
F_{\text{lab},x}
&= \gamma m_0 \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{\gamma} m_0 \frac{F_x}{m_0} \\
&=\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2} E_0 q \\
&\approx \frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2} E_0 q
\end{align}$$
This is just half of the usual result in the X direction that we would classically find in the lab frame.

Also,
$$\begin{align}
F_{\text{lab},y}
&= \gamma^3 \frac{1}{\gamma^3} m_0 \alpha_y \\
&= F_y \\
&= \gamma_v E_0 q
\end{align}$$ 
where $\gamma_v= 1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$.

Comment: maybe you could post your equations here... otherwise its not easy to know what you did wrong.

Comment: equations contain lot of symbols and signs. i dont know how those can be written here.

Comment: i am describing the steps i followed. with respect to the frame of moving test charge, ie rest frame of TC, i found the electrostatic forces exerted upon the TC. here i consider the relative velocity of principal charge wrt TC frame while computing γ factor . next F parallel= F parallel as it would have been had it been in rest wrt to TC, in the direction parallel to V relat.  F perpend= γ times F perpend, as it would have been had it been in rest wrt to TC, in the direction normal to V relat. next i resolved those forces in X direction and Y direction.

Comment: • The velocity of test charge wrt to lab= U
• The velocity of field charge wrt lab= V
• Hence the velocity of test charge q wrt field charge Q=(V-U)/ 1- V.U /c^2 = V-U  , since v and u are perpendicular .
• Hence γrel= 1/(1-(v^2+u^2)/c^2

Comment: • The proper force in perpendicular direction on q = γrel Fperpend
• The proper force in parallel direction on q= Fparallel
• F=vectorQq/4πε0y^2
• Resolving F in X and Y direction
• Fx=1/2*(v^2/c^2)*Qq/4πε0y^2

Comment: my enquiry was whether magnetic field is purely a relativistic phenomenon . answer is positive in case parallel moving point charges. I am on investigation of the case when two point charges move in perpendicular directions.

Comment: as it is said a magnetic force may be seen as a fully electrostatic force from an appropriate frame, I am trying to find it. I have got it for point charges having distance vector perpendicular to the direction of their relative velocities. I am yet to judge it for general cases i.e non perpendicular.

Comment: `\perp` and `\parallel` will give you $\perp$ and $\parallel$.